# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation when using $.post but not $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying use FormData to post data to another url, the following code doesn't work

```
        $("form").on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                //var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); Tried this
                $.post('myphpfile', formData, function(data){alert(data)});
        });
```

But the following $.ajax works

```
        $("form").on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "myphpfile",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data)
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });             
        });
```

I am used to $.post so what is the equivalent of the above function in $.post.

Answer (score 0):

$.post needs string or plain object for data parameter.
So you can use stringify for your formdata like following:

```
$.post('myphpfile', JSON.stringify(formData), function(data){alert(data)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a line of code below somewhere before the $.post call, your code will work. Be aware that it will affect all the $.ajax and its shorthand methods behaviour.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ contentType: false, processData: false });
```